# Why is the SwiftUI TextEditor glitching upon font size changes?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a TextEditor view where the user can customize the font size, but whenever I adjust the font size using a Slider and go back to typing in the TextEditor, the TextEditor starts glitching: the scroll position jumps up and down, the cursor ends up in the wrong position, and the text flickers.

Here's a reduced test case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var textSize: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $textSize, in: 20.0...80.0)
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .font(.system(size: textSize, weight: .semibold))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Just type some text, adjust the font size, type more text. You might need to repeat that a few times, but it eventually starts glitching.

My hypothesis is that part of the UI isn't being updated on the main thread, but maybe that's just me coming from UIKit and not fully understanding SwiftUI yet.

Using Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.2.

Comment: same with this year's releases. just junk.